# Can a sequence coverall the real numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Is there any sequence coverall the real numbers?
Like ∀x∈R ,∃n∈N  s.t. a_n = x.

I think the answer is not, but I need help to prove this, if you have some argument please comment it.

Comment: No, otherwise the real numbers would be countable. (Cf. Cantor‘s second diagonal argument.)

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#Real_numbers

Comment: To add to the previous comments: Think of it like this. The maximum cardinality of the image of the sequence is achieved if it's one to one. But then you have a bijection with the natural numbers.